# target specific glibc ABI

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, abi

I want to compile a dynamically linked executable on Linux, and I want to target an older glibc ABI to ensure that it can run on as many linux computers as possible.  I know that the typical solution to this is to use a chroot or virtual machine, install an old toolchain, and let the toolchain naturally target an older glibc ABI, but I wonder if there is a way to explicitly tell the compiler "Hey, I want you to depend on version GLIBCXX_3.4.11".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hey, I want you to depend on version GLIBCXX_3.4.11

Note that `GLIBCXX` is about `libstdc++`, and *not* about `glibc`.

The compiler (actually the linker) records required version, such as `GLIBCXX_3.4.11`, when you link your program against `libstdc++.so` and use some symbol which has changed in that version.

The only way you can avoid this is by arranging to link against a different version of `libstdc++.so`, and *that* is easiest to achieve via `chroot`, or by not using the corresponding symbol. So no, you can't just say "I want GLIBCXX_3.4.11".

Comment: Yes, I mixed up the C and C++ runtime libraries.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I will just link on an older system.  Thanks!